# How to disable a widget area of a specific page?

Tags: plugins, themes, widgets

[image: Image 1]
This is the widget available in my ***home page***.^
[image: Image 2]
This is the widget available in my ***pages***.^

The question comes: I want to find a way to disable the "front page main widget area" in my ***pages*** but not my home page. I tried to go through plugins and the theme options and have no success.

The wordpress theme I am using is start magazine.

How to deal with this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the template being used by the pages?

Comment: You mean changing theme sorry i am a wordpress noob

Comment: In your admin menus along the left side select Pages then choose edit or quick edit on one of the pages and see if you can choose a different template in the dropdown to the one being used on the homepage. You can check which template the homepage is using by clicking edit on it also.

Comment: I have done it and the content disappeared

Comment: Ok change it back. You would need to edit the original template file. Which gets tricky.

Comment: Any plugin to achieve that?

Comment: Im not sure about that. But if you’re interested in customising your theme look into creating a child theme. A child theme basically gives you a copy of your theme that you can edit without changing original files, and those changes wont be overridden by updates. Then you can edit the template file for the chosen pages and remove widget area.

Comment: Oh I have solved it by coding by using the theme editor

Comment: Good job! Sometimes the theme updates might override your edits. So just keep that in mind if you are doing lots of customising to your original theme files, as you wont want to redo it all.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to prevent theme update will override my edits?

Comment: You need to create a “child theme”. Its quite simple if you have access to your files via cpanel. There are loads of tutorials online which tell you how to do it, but to sum it up you are creating another folder for your child theme and creating new functions.php and style.css files in there. Must be done correctly though or it wont work. Whenever you want to edit a template you can copy it from the parent theme folder into your child them folder and edit it. Therefore not editing original files and not affected by updates. Google your theme name followed by “create child theme”.

Comment: Ok thanks seems my theme latest version is almost a year ago...

Comment: Your welcome. The version wont matter in terms of creating a child theme.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)